# Stochastic thermodynamical entropy production on growing state space

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes, randomness

Suppose we have a stochastic process for a biased random walker starting at a position $x_0 = 0$. At a discrete time $n$, it can either move a distance $s^n$ to the right with probability $p$ or a distance $s^n$ with probability $q$ to the left. If we choose, e.g., $s=1/3$, the steady-state distribution for the final position is the singular ternary Cantor distribution.

I am trying to figure out the entropy production for such a system as a function of $p,\,q$ and $s$. Since at every "generation" $n$ the state space doubles, I don't know how to write a suitable Markov model for this system.

One would naively expect the entropy exchange with the environment to take a form such as
$$ \dot{S} = (p-q) \log{\left(\frac p q\right)},$$
but such an expression is not correct. To see this, consider that the particle has jumped to the right with probability $p$ at a time $n-1$. Since in the following generation $n$, the probability $q$ is not the probability to return to the position occupied at time $n-1$, but rather to move to a new position in between, a generalised detailed balance equation cannot be written down; there is no reverse path between two states connected by "forward" jumps, either to the left or right.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, each final state can only be reached by a unique sequence of left/right jumps, so the entropy of the final position is just the sum of the entropies for each individual step and that we can get the entropy for a single step directly from Shannon's formula $\Delta S = p\log p + q\log q$, so $S_n = n\Delta S$